# What should be the default value for $security?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security, symfony-2.7

I'm working on this method:

```
public function loginAction(Request $request, Security $security)
{
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $session->remove('admin_project_id');

    if ($security->has(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
        $error = $request->attributes->get(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    } else {
        $error = $session->get(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        $session->remove(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }

    return $this->render('PDOneBundle:Login:index.html.twig',
        array_merge($this->defaultViewParams(), array(
            'last_username' => $session->get(Security::LAST_USERNAME),
            'error'         => $error,
            'include_sidebar' => false,
            )
        )
    );
}
```

But I got this error when it's called:

> Controller
>   "GroupDCA\PDOneBundle\Controller\LoginController::loginAction()"
>   requires that you provide a value for the "$security" argument
>   (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional
>   argument after this one).

What should be the default value for that argument? Is the way I'm using right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first of all, you don't need to pass $security as an argument. The line where you use security, you actually have to access $request and look its attributes for an error.

Secondly, I saw you tagged the question as *symfony 2.7* and since version @2.6 a new, short way of login was introduced:

```
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render(
        'security/login.html.twig',
        array(
            // last username entered by the user
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
        )
    );
}
```

You can read more from where this piece of code was taken: [How to Build a Traditional Login Form](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html)

Comment: where is $request variable getting used here ? Will the function behave same if Request $request is not passed as an argument ?

Comment: Yes, the method would be successfully executed even without $request being passed as an argument. The code was taken (as shown below in my post) from the documentation. Frankly, I don't know why $request was left injected in there, I believe it was just forgotten when updating the docs for release 2.6 and 2.7.